# MySql `id` column has a 'PRIMARY' and a 'UNIQUE' index, is this ideal?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, unique

Everything I can find on the internet explains the *difference* between these types of indexing, that is NOT my question.

When I create a new table in a database, I always create an id primary key as I'm sure most people do. I always make it `PRIMARY KEY, NOT NULL, UNIQUE, AUTO_INCREMENT`.

I'm recently getting big into adding custom indexes and I've noticed that my id field has these two index's (automatically created, for obvious reasons):

```
There is a PRIMARY index
There is also a UNIQUE index
```

My assumption is due to the PK flag (primary key) the 'PRIMARY' index was automatically generated, and due to the `UNIQUE` flag  the 'UNIQUE' index was created.

I assume having two indexes on the same column is adding unnecessary overhead. My question is, is this true? Should I remove one of these index's? Or is it normal/ideal to have both of these index's created on my id column?

Comment: The unique key is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PRIMARY KEY(x), UNIQUE(x)` -- Since a `PRIMARY KEY` is *by definition* (in MySQL) `UNIQUE`, the later index is redundant and should be dropped.

Also, in `UNIQUE(x), INDEX(x)` the `INDEX(x)` is redundant.

Redundant indexes take up extra space.  (In a future version, they may even be disallowed -- that is how useless they are.)

Every table should (or even "must") have a `PRIMARY KEY`.  It can either be an `AUTO_INCREMENT`, or some "natural" key.  "Natural" in the sense that it is `UNIQUE` and never `NULL`.  In a brief survey, I found that only 25% of tables had an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column.

[More on indexing](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Don't to forget to consider "composite" indexes such as `INDEX(a,b)`.